# How to prevent changes in a blot in Quilljs?

Tags: javascript, quill

I created a custom blot that I would like to "lock" to prevent further changes of its content. Is there any way to stop propagating text-change event?

I tried:

```
quill.on('text-change', (...args) => { ... })
```

but the args are just deltas and source of the event, not the event itself.

I also tried:

```
quill.on('text-change', () => { quill.history.undo() })
```

But, apparently, the change is not finished yet and it doesn't work.

Or maybe, is there a way to override some blot method to make it read-only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [formula module](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/2197fc238f608bfec968dc6a7745c7fb0f821195/modules/formula.js) that is supplied with Quill does something like this. You say that you have created your own blot, so you could probably do the same as the formula blot:

```
node.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```